# MinGW не видит функции WinAPI

Tags: c++

Я написал свой ​​мейкфайл для виндовс , в файлах срр я использую WinApi функции , но выполнив команду make в MinGW , оно не хочет создавать исполняемый файл . Как подключить WINApi функции , чтобы MinGw их увидел ??

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]WinMake.txt:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c 
CLIBS = -lws2_32
win: sniffer.exe

sniffer.exe: main.o WinSniffer.o 
            $(CC) main.o WinSniffer.o $(CLIBS) -lws2_32 -o Sniffer
main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp $(CLIBS)

WinSniffer.o: WinSniffer.cpp _WINSniffer.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) WinSniffer.cpp $(CLIBS)
clean:
    rm  *.o sniffer sniffer.exe -v
```

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте

```
#include <Windows.h>
```

Если не помогло, обновите MinGW до [более свежей версии](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/).

Так же проверьте что в коде нет `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`